# What verb to use, 'Give out/emanate etc a respectable air'?

Tags: word-request

I couldn't find it in any dictionary. Google News didn't help me. 'Make air' (by analogy with 'make an impression') would sound comical. 'Have' doesn't have the meaning I seek to convey. So what verb to use with 'respectable/pompous etc air'?

Comment: It's usually just [***have** a respectable air.*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*+a+respectable+air&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2C%2A%20a%20respectable%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20respectable%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20a%20respectable%20air%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2C*%20a%20respectable%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhas%20a%20respectable%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bhave%20a%20respectable%20air%3B%2Cc0) If you want a more "active" verb, perhaps ***present / adopt / assume / give out/off** an air of respectability*. Or even ***exude***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Why 'have a respectable air' but not 'give out a respectable air'?

Comment: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/emanate) say that you can 'emanate an [adjective] air' (which surprised me, as I've always associated _emanate_ with something like warmth or a smell).

Comment: I agree with Fumble Fingers: has a respectable air. The problem with **give off** is that it is associated with **odors**, usually unpleasant. . So, if you "give off a respectable air", that **could be** rather sarcastic.

Comment: Does the Lexico entry justify my word choice?

Comment: Yes : see definition 1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A casual phrasing:

> He **gives off** an air of confidence

Something fancier:

> He **exudes** an air of confidence

Something I think is worth mentioning is that I'm not sure the whole "air of" phrasing works well with "respect". To say someone gives off/exudes an "air of respect" or a "respectable air" sounds more like a weird way of saying that someone is very respectful. But I'm guessing you mean that the person has a sort of aura about them that makes everyone else respect them. In that case you can say:

> He **commands** respect

To "command" respect implies that you comport yourself in such a way that others feel compelled to treat you with respect, as opposed to just insisting that everyone respect you automatically ("demand respect").

Comment: gives off is like a smell, in my view.

Comment: 1) What about my suggestions? 2) Why can't I use an adjective?

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev 1a.) I don't think "give out" works because that suggests actively handing something out, but air, especially in this metaphorical sense, isn't tangible like that. The air comes from the person passively; the person doesn't actively give it out. 1b.) [Merriam Webster says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emanate) emanate could work, though for me personally it sounds weird. I don't hear the transitive use of emanate very often. 2.)  You can use an adjective, but my instinct is that "air of ____" is the more common construction than "____-able air".